# jquery change the value when editing CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am building a slider and implementing a function that will get the finger position and have the element position to follow the finger.
 Everything is fine, when I put the result in the log, all fine but when I actually put that result in the css, all of sudden that same result is different... here a snippet.

```
$(document).on("touchmove", function(e){
    //clearTimeout(slide);
    var first = parseInt($(".my-slide").first().css("left"));
    var last = parseInt($(".my-slide").last().css("left"));
    if(drag){
        xEnd = e.touches[0].pageX;
        dragDistance = xEnd - x; 
        if((first + dragDistance < 0) && (last + dragDistance > 0)){
            var left = parseInt($(element).css("left"));
            var result = (left + parseInt(dragDistance))+"px";
            console.log(result)
            $(element).css("left", result)//if I coment it, result will display the correct value but if I uncomment the css manipulation, then all of sudden "result" is all wrong...
        }
    }
});
```

See, if I comment :

```
$(element).css("left", result)
```

then result is all good, correct but if I uncomment it, result is totally different

Comment: Can you build  a complete minimal example in Stack Overflow inline JS snippet?

Comment: How do i do that?